# Use runtime parameters and expressions in azure-pipelines.yml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am working on a re-usable build pipeline for all my projects and I want to be able to use parameters to define some expressions that select what projects to build in a pipeline.

I have written a sample pipeline to demonstrate what I'm attempting and where it breaks.

azure-pipelines.yml:

```yaml
trigger:
- main

parameters:
- name: deploymentEnvironmentSetting
  type: string
  default: auto
  values:
  - auto
  - none
  - dev
  - test
  - prod

steps:
  - script: |
      "Do setup"
  # VS code does not like this line
  - ${{ if eq(parmeters.deploymentEnvironmentSetting, auto)}}:
    - script: |
        "Run Auto"
```

VS Code gives this error on the commented line

> Property ${{ if eq(parmeters.deploymentEnvironmentSetting, auto)}} is not allowed

And if I push to my devops project the pipeline fails with the following error:

> azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 22, Col: 5): The expression is not closed. An unescaped ${{ sequence was found, but the closing }} sequence was not found.

If I rename my template to something other than azure-pipelines.yml, the VScode error goes away; which leads me to believe you can't do this in a non-template.

What confuses me is in the documentation at [Runtime Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops-2022&tabs=script) it states

> You can specify parameters in templates **and in the pipeline**

and even shows an example of basically what I'm trying to do here: [Use parameters to determine what steps to run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops-2022&tabs=script#use-parameters-to-determine-what-steps-run)

```
parameters:
- name: image
  displayName: Pool Image
  values:
  - windows-latest
  - ubuntu-latest
  - macOS-latest
- name: test
  displayName: Run Tests?
  type: boolean
  default: false

trigger: none

jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: Build and Test
  pool: 
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.image }}
  steps:
  - script: echo building $(Build.BuildNumber)
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.test, true) }}:
    - script: echo "Running all the tests"
```

Did I miss something in the documentation that states you can only use expressions in templates, or that you can't use parameters this way in the top level azure-pipelines.yml; or am I missing some syntax in my definition to make it work?

EDITS:

- I am running my pipelines on a self hosted Azure DevOps Server 2022 instance
- If I copy any of the examples from [use parameters outside of templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops-2022&tabs=script#use-parameters-to-set-what-configuration-is-used)
  where the expression syntax is used to select a job or step, I get the mentioned errors; however if the expression is used to only set a value on a Property within a Task or Step, there are no issues.

Example:

```yaml
# BAD
...
jobs:
- ${{ if contains(parameters.configs, 'x86') }}:
  - job: x86
    steps:
    - script: echo Building x86...
...
```

```yaml
# All Good
...
jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: build
  pool: 
    vmImage: ${{ parameters.image }}
  steps:
  - script: echo building $(Build.BuildNumber) with ${{ parameters.image }}
```

This leads me to believe there is a limitation on how expressions are used in non-templates; but I can't find any documentation that states that and the documentation that does exist leads me to believe that should be do-able.

Comment: Hi there, Glad to know the issue is resolved. Would mind accepting your finding below as an answer? It may help other community members with similar situations. Thx for the sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my issue was actually a missing closing curly bracket in my original azure-pipelines.yml and my debugging efforts ended up getting derailed by the fact that the VS Code extension does not recognize the expression syntax if the file is named azure-pipelines.yml. This was causing me to rely on the fact that VS code would error and I would assume that if I pushed the sample code from the documentation to my pipeline it would produce the same error.

Here is the actual error in my (truncated) original yaml file:

```
#file: azure-pipelines.yml
parameters:
# Define application projects. These will be published to the Application_Build artifact
- name: appProjects
  type: object
  default: 
    p1: PipelineTests
  # Define Unit test projects. These will be published to the Application_Test artifact
- name: testProjects
  type: object
  default:
    t1: UnitTests

...

steps:
# Where I thought the issue was
- ${{ each app  in parameters.appProjects }}:
      - task: CopyFiles@1
        displayName: Copy bin to binaries directory
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
          # Where the actual issue was. I was missing the closing bracket on ${{app}
          Contents: '**\${{app}\**\bin\**'
          TargetFolder: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\Apps'
          OverWrite: true
```